# Subdomain setup in IIS 8.0

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-deployment

I have uploaded my asp.net 2.0 application on a VPS through Remote Desktop. Currently I have added it in IIS as an application in default website & I use www.mydomain.com/myapp to access it through the browser.

But now I want to access it through www.someotherdomain.com instead of www.mydomain.com/myapp. Is It possible to achieve this goal through subdomains If Yes, kindle mention the procedure.

Also mention the working required if I want to access my Application through www.myapp.mydomain.com.

Since this is my first time, it will be more helpful if the solution is mentioned in detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your application from www.someotherdomain.com then simply you can ask your network provider to change the DNS from www.mydomain.com to ww.someotherdomain.com. It will work for you.

Let me know if you need any more information.